# Please help me about UI Thread of WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-interface

I am writting a project on WPF.
Before displaying main window, I must query some data from DB and then based on
the data, I will draw some user control on main window by code behind.
The processing take about 3 - 5 seconds. So when first launch mainwindows, It will display as white screen. After 3 - 5 seconds, the window will display fully.

I want to ask that, is there anyway to do display a waiting view and do the drawing user control in another thread. After finish, then load fully main window.

Please help me. Thanks in advance :).

Comment: BackgoundWorker or priority binding or splash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to offload the UI Thread. You can do it by using either `TPL` or `BackgroundWorker`. I recommend you to use `TPL` with `async-await`, as it's much easier and the code is more clear.

```
private QueryResult QueryDatabase()
{
    // Here's your db access code
    return result;
}

private Task<QueryResult> QueryDatabaseAsync()
{
    // This code will be queued to ThreadPool
    return Task.Run(QueryDatabase);
}

private async void LoadedHandler(...)
{
    IsProgressVisible = true;

    Items = await QueryDatabaseAsync();

    IsProgressVisible = false;
}
```